# aspnet core change database connection string via middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My web api follows this structure

/countrycode/mycontroller e.g. /gbr/mycontroller
I am using middleware to get the country code so I can switch connection string:

```
public class ConnectionMiddleware
{

public ConnectionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
{
    this.next = next;
}

private readonly RequestDelegate next;

public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
{            
    var values = httpContext.GetRouteData().Values;            
    await next(httpContext);
}

}
```

So now I have my country code I want to set the connection string property in my db service.

My db service is already registered in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<INpgSqlDataAccess, NpgSqlDataAccess>();
```

Can the connection string be set via my middleware now and be seen globally (after already being registered) or should I register the service in my middleware?

Comment: Is CountryCode different in every requests?

Comment: Yes, it is sent per request

Comment: How about `services.AddHttpContextAccessor().AddTransient<INpgSqlDataAccess>(provider =>  { var httpContext = provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext; return ...})`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should create a class for manage connection string.

```
public interface IDatabaseConnectionManager
{
    void SetConnectionString(string connectionString);
    string GetConnectionString();
}

public class DatabaseConnectionManager
{
    private string _connectionString;

    public DatabaseConnectionManager()
    {
        // _connectionString = DefaultConnectionString;
    }

    public void SetConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        this._connectionString = connectionString;      
    }

    public void GetConnectionString() {
        return _connectionString; 
    }
}
```

And then if you want to use middleware you can try this:

public class ConnectionMiddleware
{
private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext,IDatabaaseConnectionManager connectionManager)
{
    var connectionString = "some-connection-string"; // Create Your Connection String Here

    connectionManager.SetConnectionString(connectionString);

    await _next.InvokeAsync(httpContext);
}
```

And in your Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IDatabaseConnectionManager,DatabaseConnectionManager>();
    services.AddScoped<INgpSqlDataAccess>(options=>
    {
        var connectionManager = options.GetService<IDatabaseConnectionManager>();
        var connectionString = connectionManager.GetConnectionString();

        // Create Your SqlDataAccess With ConnectionString
        return new NgpSqlDataAccess(connectionString);
    });
}
```

Every time you resolve INgpSqlDataAccess you get a new instance with your desired connectionstring. Be carefull that you must register your dependencies with per http request life time (Scoped).

Comment: Cheers for this!

Comment: do you have any idea why what I set in middleware is not there when I resolve the service?, it is set as scoped.

Answer (score 0):

If your `DbContext` is called `AppDbContext`, you can modify the connection string in middleware like this:

```
public async Task Invoke(
    HttpContext httpContext,
    IConfiguration configuration,
    AppDbContext context)
{
    context.Database.SetConnectionString(configuration.GetConnectionString("Other"));

    await _next(httpContext);
}
```

In `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
```